# What format needs to be a property?

Tags: c#, properties

ALL,

I have a following code with C#:

```
public int property
{
    set
    {
         tbText.Text = property.ToString();
    }
    get
    {
         return Convert.ToInt32(tbText.Text);
    }
}
```

When I go to the properties Window, I see the message:

Input string was not in the right format.

tbText is a TextBox control on which I am trying to get or set value.

Initially the control is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) keyword in your setter.

> The contextual keyword **value** is used in the set accessor in ordinary
>   property declarations. It is similar to an input parameter on a
>   method.

```
public int property
{
    get
    {             
         int defaultVal;
         int.TryParse(tbText.Text, out defaultVal);
         return defaultVal;
    }
    set
    {
         tbText.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for convention reasons, it is preferred to place the get accessor before the set accessor.

Comment: @canon, thank you, I changed it but that is only half of the problem. I am receiving this: "Code generation for the property failed. Error was: Property accessor on object threw the following exception: Input string was not in a correct format". Any idea?

Comment: You will also want to validate input to insure it is an integer.  You could add a CompareValidator on the front end or use a tryparse or try/catch in the accessor.

Comment: Because `defaultVal` is an `out` parameter, there's no need to say `= 0`, i.e. to assign to it before the `TryParse` call. The value you assign to it (here `0`) is guaranteed to be discarded and replaced anyway, so is never used.

Comment: @canon, I have one more question, sorry to bother you again. What I need is when the control is disabled then it should be empty. With this code it always displays 0. So even trying to check in the code I can't override it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using setters you need to set it to the keyword `value`:

```
public int property
{
    set
    {
        tbText.Text = value.ToString();
    }
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(tbText.Text);
    }
}
```

So when setting `property`:

```
property = 100; // value is equal to whatever you are making property equal.
```

Hope this helps!